# MemoryCache case insensitive key lookup

Tags: .net

I'm trying to find a way to make the .net 4.0 MemoryCache.Default instance use a case insensitive comparer.

Is that possible?

```
var bob = new object();

MemoryCache.Default["Bob"] = bob;

bob == MemoryCache.Default["bob"]; --> true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From looking at the code through [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), it doesn't appear to be possible. Because behind the scenes it is ultimately using the `GetHashCode()` of your key string.

I think the easiest work-around for this, is to implement a custom cache, extending `MemoryCache` that overrides all methods that interact with the key, and calls `ToUpperInvariant()` when passing it as parameter to the base call.